# Canvas fillRect has wrong X coordinate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am attempting to create a javascript function which will color the pixels of a canvas underneath the cursor. When it runs, colored pixels appear on the left edge of the browser, though they are in the correct vertical position. Here are my functions:

```
function writecolor(event) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("colcan");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var stylestr;
    var permuda = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    var os = $("#colcan").offset();
    var x= event.X-os.left;
    var y= event.clientY-os.top;
    console.log(x);
    var str = "#";

    for (x=0; x<6;x++) {
        str += permuda.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*16));
    }
    ctx.fillStyle = str;
    ctx.fillRect(x,y,1,1);
}

function setdim() {
    var canv = document.getElementById("colcan");
    canv.height=$(window).height();
    canv.width=$(window).width();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
             setdim();
              $(window).on("resize", function() {setdim()});
              $("#colcan").on("mousemove", function(event) { writecolor(event)});
              });
```

I can tell from the console that the correct X coordinate is being read on mousemove. I have been unable to figure out why the pixels are not appearing in the correct horizontal position. Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xt87kb2q/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the console i am getting the x coordinate as NaN

their is no "event.x"

you need to do "event.clientX" to get the X coordinate

And one more thing
you are first definig a var x where the value is stored, 
next right below it you are running a for loop, were the value of X is 6 which is why things are not working out.

If you console the value of x right before it is painting the canvas, you can see it is always printing 6.
and you are running a for loop till 6....hence for every mouse movement you are getting wrong X.